# Did I do this big-O notation correctly?

Tags: big-o

It is for a homework assignment and I'm just getting thrown a little bit by the negative sign.

> Express the following in terms of big-O notation. Use the tightest bounds possible. For instance, n5 is technically O(n1000), but this is not as tight as O(n5).
>
> n<sup>2</sup> −500n−2

- n<sup>2</sup> - 500 n - 2
- <= n<sup>2</sup> - 500 n
- <= n<sup>2</sup> for all n > 0
- which is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: The negative sign should not bother you. Yes, if n=10, then it'd be a negative number, but what if the `n` is sufficiently _large_ ?

Comment: E.g. see these two graphs: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bn%5E2+%E2%88%92500*n%E2%88%922%2C+n%5E2%7D%2C%7Bn%2C1000%2C1200%7D%5D) - `n^2` for sufficiently large n is _always_ larger than `n^2-500n-2`

Comment: in short, yes you did it correctly

Comment: There is also a theoretical computer science stack exchange site, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/, that can be used for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Big O notation what you need to remember is that it only matters for some number x<sub>0</sub> and all numbers above that.  Specifically `f(x)= O(g(x))` as x approaches infinity if there is some number `M` and some real number x<sub>0</sub> such that `|f(x)| <= M|g(x)|` for all x >= x<sub>0</sub>. [(Source for equations, wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Basically, we only need to consider large values of x and you can pick an arbitrarily large value.  So large in fact that `n^2` will overshadow a subtraction by `500n`.  To be more technical if I pick M to be 2 and x<sub>0</sub> to be 100000000000000000. Then the above equation holds.  I'm being lazy and picking an x<sub>0</sub> that is extremely large but the equation lets me.  For an M equal to 2 a much smaller value of x<sub>0</sub> would work, but again, it doesn't matter.

Finally, your answer of `O(n^2)` is correct

Answer (score 1):

Yes  `O(n^2)` is correct. The negative sign should not bother you. Yes, if `n = 10`, then it'd be a negative number, but what if the `n` is sufficiently large?

E.g. see these two graphs: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bn%5E2%20%E2%88%92500%2An%E2%88%922%2C%20n%5E2%7D%2C%7Bn%2C1000%2C1200%7D%5D) - `n^2` for sufficiently large `n` is always larger than `n^2-500n-2`.